# What is the difference between "gewöhnlich" and "für gewöhnlich"?

Tags: word-usage

[DWDS shows many examples of the adverbial use of gewöhnlich](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%40gew%C3%B6hnlich&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50), including:

> Wenn Mitteleuropäer wilde Tiere in freier Wildbahn sehen wollen, müssen sie **gewöhnlich** weit, weit fahren.

> Und das dauert, stimmt die Bewegung, **für gewöhnlich** nicht lang.

> Jede Nacht hat er Albträume und wacht **gewöhnlich** davon auf, dass er das Bett einnässt.

> Nach dreißig Minuten gehe er **für gewöhnlich** zurück in seine Wohnung und widme sich dem Schreiben.

Why is it just "gewöhnlich" in some cases and "für gewöhnlich" in others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. They mean the same thing.

According to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gewoehnlich) "für gewöhnlich" is more common while [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gew%C3%B6hnlich) marks it as elevated speech.

As usual, I would assume that prevalence also strongly depends on the region but both are perfectly fine and well-understood.